# How to dump whole database from remote server on sequel pro

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have a database connection to a remote host on SequelPro Mac OSX. How can i dump whole database. I need a dump like what `mysqldump` command does:

```
$ mysqldump --opt -u [uname] -p[pass] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]
```

I found the table dump option, but i need full database dump.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can dump database with SequelPro (Mac OSX) with `File > Export (⇧⌘E)` option.